# Is there a PHP framework considered to be Ruby's Ruby On Rails?

Tags: php

The PHP community has been so vastly fragmented with lots of frameworks while Ruby only has Ruby on Rails being the sole framework of choice of the masses. Although there's also minor players like Sinatra but you know what I mean.

I believe there has been great improvements in PHP lately except the frameworks kept multiplying relentlessly. As I remember back then, there was Mojavi, Symfony, CakePHP, CodeIgniter, Kohana, Zend, then there was Yii, DooPHP, FuelPHP among others, not to mention the "thin" frameworks like FatFree, Slim, Recess, FRAPI, Tonic, etc...

I am having trouble deciding which is which. For example, I have long abandoned CodeIgniter and now that I am just about to consider FuelPHP, suddenly a new client requires me to code in CodeIgniter.

I am beginning to think I should convert to Ruby and avoid all these fragments altogether. Since most of the "converts" treat it like religion, I'm intrigued I might achieve inner peace if I do :-)

I honestly think the PHP community could do well if all the authors of these great frameworks unite as one, make the ultimate framework and name it possibly Zend Framework "Done Right". Feel me?

Now my question is, as experienced programmers, is there any PHP framework that you think is heading on the right track? As we know Zend should've done it but the community feedback was otherwise. Is there a framework right now in the PHP realm, that in due time will probably be recognized as PHP's RoR?

Comment: "ultimate framework" according to who? There's a reason why there are choices.

Comment: *Ruby on Rails* is for *Ruby*. There is no PHP equivalent. That is, use RoR if you want RoR :)

Comment: @webbiedave Ummm, according to the community? Thing is some of my clients wants Symfony, some Code Igniter, some Cake. It is very hard to be an "expert" in a framework when clients "know" what they want. While my Ruby friends drinks juice coding in the beach.

Comment: @IMB: Obviously each of these authors believe theirs is the best way. They each have their own priorities (RAD, TDD, etc...). You'll have to determine which of each framework's set of priorities lines up best with your client's priorities.

Answer (score 4):

[PHPonTrax](http://www.phpontrax.com/) is an attempt to mimic Ruby On Rails in PHP

Comment: +1 because this is the only meaningful way to answer this question.